# Не выполняется функция преобразования числа в пропись на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, функции, aimylogic

Проектирую бота на lowcode платформе Aimylogic. Их система упорно не хочет работать с этим кодом преобразования чисел в пропись.
Причем в песочницах он работает. Со знаками $ не очень корректно, а вот с var хорошо.

```js
$number = 12545,34;
$prod_time = function number_to_string() {
        $arr_numbers = new Array();
        $arr_numbers[1] = new Array('', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять', 'одиннадцать', 'двенадцать', 'тринадцать', 'четырнадцать', 'пятнадцать', 'шестнадцать', 'семнадцать', 'восемнадцать', 'девятнадцать');
        $arr_numbers[2] = new Array('', '', 'двадцать', 'тридцать', 'сорок', 'пятьдесят', 'шестьдесят', 'семьдесят', 'восемьдесят', 'девяносто');
        $arr_numbers[3] = new Array('', 'сто', 'двести', 'триста', 'четыреста', 'пятьсот', 'шестьсот', 'семьсот', 'восемьсот', 'девятьсот');
        function number_parser() {
                $string = '';
                $num_hundred = '';
                if ($num.length == 3) {
                        $num_hundred = $num.substr(0, 1);
                        $num = $num.substr(1, 3);
                        $string = $arr_numbers[3][$num_hundred] + ' ';
                }
                if ($num < 20) $string += $arr_numbers[1][parseFloat($num)] + ' ';
                else {
                        $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
                        $second_num = $num.substr(1, 2);
                        $string += $arr_numbers[2][$first_num] + ' ' + $arr_numbers[1][$second_num] + ' ';
                }              
                switch ($desc){
                        case 0:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'рубль';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'рубль';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num)  $string += 'рубля';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length > 1) $string += 'рублей';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && $last_num  > 4) $string += 'рублей';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && 0 == $last_num) $string += 'Ноль рублей';
                                else $string += 'рубль';
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысяча ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'тысяча ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысячи ';
                                else $string += 'тысяч ';
                                $string = $string.replace('один ', 'одна ');
                                $string = $string.replace('два ', 'две ');
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                $last_num = parseFloat(_num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллион ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллион ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиона ';
                                else $string += 'миллионов ';
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиард ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллиард ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиарда ';
                                else $string += 'миллиардов ';
                                break;
                }
                $string = $string.replace('  ', ' ');
                return $string;
        }
        function decimals_parser() {
                $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
                $second_num = parseFloat($num.substr(1, 2));
                $string = ' ' + $first_num + $second_num;
                if ($second_num == 1 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейка';
                else if ($second_num > 1 && $second_num < 5 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейки';
                else $string += ' копеек';
                return $string;
         }
          if (!$number || $number == 0) return 'Ноль рублей';
          if (typeof $number !== 'number') {
                  $number = $number.replace(',', '.');
                  $number = parseFloat(number);
                  if (isNaN($number)) return 'Ноль рублей';
         }
        $number = $number.toFixed(2);
        if($number.indexOf('.') != -1) {
                $number_arr = $number.split('.');
                $number = $number_arr[0];
                $number_decimals = $number_arr[1];
        }
        $number_length = $number.length;
        $string = '';
        $num_parser = '';
        $count = 0;
        for ($p = ($number_length - 1); $p >= 0; $p--) {
                $num_digit = $number.substr($p, 1);
                $num_parser = $num_digit +  $num_parser;
                if (($num_parser.length == 3 || $p == 0) && !isNaN(parseFloat($num_parser))) {
                        $string = number_parser($num_parser, $count) + $string;
                        $num_parser = '';
                        $count++;
                }
        }
        if ($number_decimals) $string += decimals_parser($number_decimals);
        $string = $string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $string.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        return $string;
}
```

В общем, говорили объявить эту функцию переменной, как и сделал. Убрать аргументы тоже сделал. Все равно не отрабатывает.
Выдает ошибку

> RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.justai.zb.scenarios.errors.ScriptingException: :3 TypeError: Cannot read property "prod_time" from undefined

Comment: не понятно причем тут `java` и `javascript` в одном флаконе, на чем Вы пишите? ошибка как будто пишите на `java` код как буд-то вообще из `php` там переменные начинаются с `$` а в тегах вопроса `javascript`. все что Вам нужно перевести код на нужный язык.

Comment: Смотрите. Сама платформа Aimylogic видимо написана на java поэтому и выдает ошибку с название языка. Конструктор поддерживает ванильный js и библиотеки undercore и moments. В документации к платформе написано, что вызов любой переменной нужно начинать со знака доллара США. 
https://help.aimylogic.com/docs/ru/how-to-create-a-script/bot-response/code

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте тэг платформы к вопросу через правку, это поможет знатокам быстрее найти Ваш вопрос. В данном случае не находится свойство `prod_time` знаете ли почему это может быть? Это явно происходит где-то вне этого кода, поищите где у Вас используется свойство `.prod_time` в коде, тут оно объявлено как `$prod_time` в самом начале

Comment: Если не можете найти скиньте в вопрос больше текста который появляется с этой ошибкой.

Comment: В первой же строчке сразу фигня: `$number = 12545,34;` - что тут запятая делает?

Comment: я немогу добавить тег т.к. еще мало рейтинга у меня.

Comment: я добавил тег, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с моим ответом, в конце я исправил функцию. Если мой ответ окажется полезным не забудьте отметить это либо + либо галочкой, либо и тем и другим)

Answer (score 0):

> RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.justai.zb.scenarios.errors.ScriptingException: :3 TypeError:
> Cannot read property "prod_time" from undefined

Буквально эта ошибка говорит от том что в сценариях произошла ошибка так как у некторорого объекта назовем его `Object` нет свойства `prod_time` т.е:

```
Object.prod_time === undefined // true
Object.prod_time()             // будет ошибка
```

Я проанализировал код функции, чтобы она заработала во вложенных функциях не хватает `параметров` а именно:

```
function number_parser($num, $desc) {...}

function decimals_parser($num) {...}
```

Вот рабочий пример, с этими изменениями (но результат функции не правильный).

```js
$number = 13545,34;
$prod_time = function number_to_string() {
        $arr_numbers = new Array();
        $arr_numbers[1] = new Array('', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять', 'одиннадцать', 'двенадцать', 'тринадцать', 'четырнадцать', 'пятнадцать', 'шестнадцать', 'семнадцать', 'восемнадцать', 'девятнадцать');
        $arr_numbers[2] = new Array('', '', 'двадцать', 'тридцать', 'сорок', 'пятьдесят', 'шестьдесят', 'семьдесят', 'восемьдесят', 'девяносто');
        $arr_numbers[3] = new Array('', 'сто', 'двести', 'триста', 'четыреста', 'пятьсот', 'шестьсот', 'семьсот', 'восемьсот', 'девятьсот');
        function number_parser($num, $desc) {
                $string = '';
                $num_hundred = '';
                if ($num.length == 3) {
                        $num_hundred = $num.substr(0, 1);
                        $num = $num.substr(1, 3);
                        $string = $arr_numbers[3][$num_hundred] + ' ';
                }
                if ($num < 20) $string += $arr_numbers[1][parseFloat($num)] + ' ';
                else {
                        $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
                        $second_num = $num.substr(1, 2);
                        $string += $arr_numbers[2][$first_num] + ' ' + $arr_numbers[1][$second_num] + ' ';
                }              
                switch ($desc){
                        case 0:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'рубль';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'рубль';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num)  $string += 'рубля';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length > 1) $string += 'рублей';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && $last_num  > 4) $string += 'рублей';
                                else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && 0 == $last_num) $string += 'Ноль рублей';
                                else $string += 'рубль';
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысяча ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'тысяча ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысячи ';
                                else $string += 'тысяч ';
                                $string = $string.replace('один ', 'одна ');
                                $string = $string.replace('два ', 'две ');
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                $last_num = parseFloat(_num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллион ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллион ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиона ';
                                else $string += 'миллионов ';
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
                                $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
                                $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
                                $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
                                if ($last_num == 1 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиард ';
                                else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллиард ';
                                else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1!= $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиарда ';
                                else $string += 'миллиардов ';
                                break;
                }
                $string = $string.replace('  ', ' ');
                return $string;
        }
        function decimals_parser($num) {
                $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
                $second_num = parseFloat($num.substr(1, 2));
                $string = ' ' + $first_num + $second_num;
                if ($second_num == 1 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейка';
                else if ($second_num > 1 && $second_num < 5 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейки';
                else $string += ' копеек';
                return $string;
         }
          if (!$number || $number == 0) return 'Ноль рублей';
          if (typeof $number !== 'number') {
                  $number = $number.replace(',', '.');
                  $number = parseFloat(number);
                  if (isNaN($number)) return 'Ноль рублей';
         }
        $number = $number.toFixed(2);
        if($number.indexOf('.') != -1) {
                $number_arr = $number.split('.');
                $number = $number_arr[0];
                $number_decimals = $number_arr[1];
        }
        $number_length = $number.length;
        $string = '';
        $num_parser = '';
        $count = 0;
        for ($p = ($number_length - 1); $p >= 0; $p--) {
                $num_digit = $number.substr($p, 1);
                $num_parser = $num_digit +  $num_parser;
                if (($num_parser.length == 3 || $p == 0) && !isNaN(parseFloat($num_parser))) {
                        $string = number_parser($num_parser, $count) + $string;
                        $num_parser = '';
                        $count++;
                }
        }
        if ($number_decimals) $string += decimals_parser($number_decimals);
        $string = $string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $string.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        return $string;
}

console.log($prod_time())
```

> ```
> 13545.34 -> Тринадцать тысяч тринадцать тысяч  00 копеек
> ```

Поэтому я внес правки чтобы он работал корректно и прокомментировал их в коде (так как там по месту легче понять о чем речь):

```js
$number = 134212545.34;
$prod_time = function number_to_string() {
  $arr_numbers = new Array();
  $arr_numbers[1] = new Array('', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять', 'одиннадцать', 'двенадцать', 'тринадцать', 'четырнадцать', 'пятнадцать', 'шестнадцать', 'семнадцать', 'восемнадцать', 'девятнадцать');
  $arr_numbers[2] = new Array('', '', 'двадцать', 'тридцать', 'сорок', 'пятьдесят', 'шестьдесят', 'семьдесят', 'восемьдесят', 'девяносто');
  $arr_numbers[3] = new Array('', 'сто', 'двести', 'триста', 'четыреста', 'пятьсот', 'шестьсот', 'семьсот', 'восемьсот', 'девятьсот');

  function number_parser($num, $desc) { // нужны параметры
    let $string = ''; // должна быть локальная переменная let или var
    $num_hundred = '';
    if ($num.length == 3) {
      $num_hundred = $num.substr(0, 1);
      $num = $num.substr(1, 3);
      $string = $arr_numbers[3][$num_hundred] + ' ';
    }
    if (+$num < 20) $string += $arr_numbers[1][parseFloat($num)] + ' '; /* + сравнивать число не строку */
    else {
      $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
      $second_num = $num.substr(1, 2);
      $string += $arr_numbers[2][$first_num] + ' ' + $arr_numbers[1][$second_num] + ' ';
    }
    switch ($desc) {
      case 0:
        $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
        $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
        $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
        $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
        if ($last_num == 1 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'рубль';
        else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'рубль';
        else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'рубля';
        else if ($pre_last_num.length > 1) $string += 'рублей';
        else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && $last_num > 4) $string += 'рублей';
        else if ($pre_last_num.length = 1 && 0 == $last_num) $string += 'рублей'; // не 'Ноль рублей'
        else $string += 'рубль';
        break;
      case 1:
        $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
        $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
        $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
        $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
        if ($last_num == 1 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысяча ';
        else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'тысяча ';
        else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'тысячи ';
        else $string += 'тысяч ';
        $string = $string.replace('один ', 'одна ');
        $string = $string.replace('два ', 'две ');
        break;
      case 2:
        $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
        $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
        $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
        $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
        if ($last_num == 1) $string += 'миллион ';
        else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллион ';
        else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллион ';
        else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиона ';
        else $string += 'миллионов ';
        break;
      case 3:
        $last_num = parseFloat($num.substr(-1));
        $pre_last_num = $num.substr(-2);
        $pre_last_num = $pre_last_num.split("");
        $pre_last_num = parseFloat($pre_last_num[0]);
        if ($last_num == 1 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиард ';
        else if ($last_num == 1 && 1 == $pre_last_num.length) $string += 'миллиард ';
        else if ($last_num > 1 && $last_num < 5 && 1 != $pre_last_num) $string += 'миллиарда ';
        else $string += 'миллиардов ';
        break;
    }
    return $string;
  }

  function decimals_parser($num) { // нужны параметры
    $first_num = $num.substr(0, 1);
    $second_num = parseFloat($num.substr(1, 2));
    $string = ' ' + $first_num + $second_num;
    if ($second_num == 1 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейка';
    else if ($second_num > 1 && $second_num < 5 && 1 != $first_num) $string += ' копейки';
    else $string += ' копеек';
    return $string;
  }
  if (!$number || $number == 0) return 'Ноль рублей';
  if (typeof $number !== 'number') {
    $number = $number.replace(',', '.');
    $number = parseFloat($number);
    if (isNaN($number)) return 'Ноль рублей';
  }
  $number = $number.toFixed(2);
  if ($number.indexOf('.') != -1) {
    $number_arr = $number.split('.');
    $number = $number_arr[0];
    $number_decimals = $number_arr[1];
  }
  $number_length = $number.length;
  $string = '';
  $num_parser = '';
  $count = 0;
  for ($p = ($number_length - 1); $p >= 0; $p--) {
    $num_digit = $number.substr($p, 1);
    $num_parser = $num_digit + $num_parser;
    if (($num_parser.length == 3 || $p == 0) && !isNaN(parseFloat($num_parser))) {
      $string = number_parser($num_parser, $count) + $string;
      $num_parser = '';
      $count++;
    }
  }
  if ($number_decimals) $string += decimals_parser($number_decimals, 2);
  $string = $string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $string.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  $string = $string.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  return $string;
}

console.log($prod_time())
```

> ```
> 134212545.34 -> Сто тридцать четыре миллиона 
> двести двенадцать тысяч пятьсот сорок пять рублей 34 копейки
> ```

*Форматирование кода можете восстановить [тут](https://beautifier.io/) укажите количество пробелов 8*

Comment: у меня тоже в песочницах код отрабатывает. в Aimylogic посоветовали убрать аргументы из функций потому, что бот крашится.

Comment: можно ли запускать код без агументов для подфункций? 
ругается как раз таки на аргументы
src/main.sc:1718:51 Expected , but found .                    function number_parser($session.num, $session.desc) {sandbox.checkInterrupted();                                                    ^DEPLOY FAILED!

Comment: Вряд ли это переменные сессии это внутренние переменные, не знаю кто Вам советовал убрать аргументы но скорее всего это ошибочно  

По поводу Вашего кода, очень странно если он у Вас работает верно, тут много логических ошибок не связанных с языком программирования – 

Откуда у вас берется это `$number = 134212545.34` может быть это как раз то что нужно брать из сессии? 

`DEPLOY FAILED` может быть вызван разными причинами, если есть тесты то возможно они валятся, тут без дополнительных деталей в вопросе не разобраться нужны подробные логи и обстоятельства.

Comment: $number = 134212545.34 берется из сценария бота. На этапе вопроса пользователь вводит сумму цифрами она записывается в переменную и дальше эта переменная поступает в функцию для форматирования в текст.

Comment: В общем,  решил проблему следующим образом. Я вывел форматирование чисел на удаленное вычисление из сценария Aimylogic. Число записывается в переменную она через вебхук передается на в сервис n8n в  кубик Function Item там все работает как обычная функция без $и танцев с бубнами. Там функция отлично все отрабатывает. Далее, через кубик Webhook Respose значение форматирования отправляется обратно в Aimylogic. Там я опять записываю его в переменную и использую дальше в сценарии.

Comment: ну если на скорость не влияет тоже вариант, но я бы разобрался на вашем месте, просто чтобы знать как это делать правильно